# why accessing same class data from two typescript files gives different result in typescript? How to fix that?

Tags: typescript

I have created 3 typescript files named dataService.ts, init.ts, interest.ts
From this dataService.ts file is common file used to store and retrieve data from other 2 files.

In dataService.ts file

```
export default class DataService {
    private static temp1 = null;
    private static temp2 = null;

    public static setData(property: string, value: any) {
        DataService[property] = value;
    }

    public static getData(property: string) {
        return DataService[property];
    }
}
```

In init.ts file

```
import DataService from './common/dataService';

export default async function init() {
    DataService.setData('temp1', 'init');
    console.log('Data service from init ', DataService.getData('temp1'));
    console.log('Data service from init ', DataService.getData('temp2'));
}

init();
```

In interest.ts file

```
import DataService from './common/dataService';
export default async function interest() {
    DataService.setData('temp2', 'interest');
    console.log('Data service from interest ', DataService.getData('temp1'));
    console.log('Data service from interest ', DataService.getData('temp2'));
}

interest();
```

If I run first init function it gives result as

```
Data service from init init
Data service from init null
```

which is perfect but after init.ts if I run interest.ts file then it gives output as

```
Data service from interest null
Data service from interest interest
```

and I want this interest output as

```
Data service from interest init
Data service from interest interest
```

because value of temp1 was set by init.ts. How can I do this type of global content sharing in typescript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running this code in the TS playground

[link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=28&pc=12#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiYBcwGUCmAnAbgS2K6A3gLABQ050ADutpovhEgrtAqgLaUCM0AvNADsAriBABuUhSo06baI0Qs2nAEx9BI8aUkVKQgEYgWC5sHmoE8JAApqAe0oYEATwBc0ANapndgGZxEFAwcPAAaaDoQIVR3RhoBAHMASkIdKXIrIKxcVABte0d0FwBddUjoiTIKAF9tKvI9Q2MmFgSLTNt0Byc3T28-AKQ0bLwU4nr09AshdAFBrJC8gp7iyqlakg3SSGcBM18hPeY7OewBbARrMbT54cWAOgh2wOsAcmVuV-DXs4vXpLWFGAJwgdhAqHuIDsCTemXMI3wvi67GgvwQ0C%20t2COXubUsL3eHE%20SQBN2BAlB4Mh0NhgXhi2gSLsKLRGPCmTuOLxHUJqn%20pM2dTRV0q2wgu32h2Ax1OAjYU0YV1SEw52Lwj2eNl5lBUmJ%20cowqEY-0B5HJlIhUJhrzhTwRjORqINCvRmNVCNxmrAbw%20XH5pug5rBlppNrpdoZTJZzqNrvZgU56u5BI%20upJlS2JDO8tjIqAA)

You can see this works as expected.
So My guess here would be that you are just accidentally running this in 2 separate runs.